# How to retrieve Expression Atlas baseline expression results in JSON format?

Tags: gene-expression, api

I'm looking to retrieve Expression Atlas baseline expression results in JSON format, e.g. the results on [this page](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/genes/ensg00000204301?bs=%7B%22homo%20sapiens%22%3A%5B%22ORGANISM_PART%22%5D%7D&ds=%7B%22kingdom%22%3A%5B%22animals%22%5D%7D#baseline).

Several years ago I did a similar thing but looking at differential expression results, and was able to access the json format for those [results here](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/gxa/json/search/differential_results?geneQuery=%255B%257B%2522value%2522%253A%2522ENSG00000204301%2522%257D%255D&conditionQuery=&species=homo%20sapiens). However, I can't figure out how to access the baseline expression result equivalent.

Does anyone know how to access the baseline expression results in JSON format, or know how I could find out how to do this?

Comment: I'd email the support for that group. EBI is pretty good at getting back to you in general: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/support/gxa